# SQL script for merging customer accounts

Tags: sql-server

I have come up with a script to select the "Master" account and "Slave" account. Where the company name and postal code match exactly. It deems the most recently updated account to be the master.

```
select
    m.ev870_acct_code, m.ev870_company_name, m.ev870_postal_code, m.ev870_iacvb_code,
    s.ev870_acct_code, s.ev870_company_name, s.ev870_postal_code, s.ev870_iacvb_code
from
    ev870_acct_master m
inner join
    ev870_acct_master s
on
    m.ev870_company_name = s.ev870_company_name
and m.ev870_postal_code = s.ev870_postal_code
and m.ev870_upd_stamp > s.ev870_upd_stamp
where
    m.ev870_class = 'o'
and s.ev870_class = 'o'
and m.ev870_status != '0'
and s.ev870_status != '0'
and (m.ev870_iacvb_code = s.ev870_iacvb_code or isnull(m.ev870_iacvb_code,'') = '' or isnull(s.ev870_iacvb_code,'') = '')
and s.ev870_company_name like '%council%'
order by
    m.ev870_upd_stamp desc
```

The issue with the script as it stands is that it may determine that:

- Account 1 is the master and a duplicate slave Account 2 exists.
- Account 1 is the master and a duplicate slave Account 3 exists.
- Account 2 is the master and a duplicate slave Account 3 exists.

As you can see the result of each step would impact the following step. Can you recommend a smarter query?

*EDIT* Solution:

```
select
    m.ev870_acct_code, m.ev870_company_name, m.ev870_postal_code, m.ev870_iacvb_code,
    s.ev870_acct_code, s.ev870_company_name, s.ev870_postal_code, s.ev870_iacvb_code
from
    ev870_acct_master s
inner join 
    (
    select 
        ev870_acct_code, ev870_company_name, ev870_postal_code, ev870_iacvb_code, ev870_upd_stamp
        ,row_number() over (partition by ev870_company_name, ev870_postal_code, ev870_iacvb_code order by ev870_upd_stamp desc) as howRecent
    from 
        ev870_acct_master
    where
        ev870_class = 'o'
    and ev870_status != '0'
    and ev870_postal_code != ''
    and ev870_company_name like 'A%'
    ) m 
on  
    m.ev870_company_name = s.ev870_company_name
and m.ev870_postal_code = s.ev870_postal_code
and m.ev870_upd_stamp > s.ev870_upd_stamp
where
    m.howRecent = 1
and m.ev870_iacvb_code = s.ev870_iacvb_code
and s.ev870_class = 'o'
and s.ev870_status != '0'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: @Lee can you explain a bit more what you are trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: SQL Server 2005. @kristof i am identifying duplicate accounts in my application which will then be merge into a single account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to follow on your comment:

> @kristof i am identifying duplicate accounts in my application which
>   will then be merge into a single account.

You could use a code similar to this:

```
declare @dupExample table (
    id int identity(1,1)
    ,name varchar(50)
    ,postal varchar(50)
    ,lastUpdated datetime
)

insert into @dupExample(name, postal, lastUpdated)
values 
    ('a','pc1','20120101')
    ,('a','pc1','20120501')
    ,('a','pc1','20120601')
    ,('a','pc1','20120701')
    ,('a','pc1','20120201')
    ,('b','pc2','20120102')
    ,('b','pc2','20120202')
    ,('b','pc2','20120302')
    ,('b','pc2','20120302')
    ,('c','pc2','20120302')
    ,('d','pc2','20120302')
    ,('d','pc2','20120302')


select * from @dupExample 


/*
    to see duplicates along with how recent they are
*/
select 
    *
    ,row_number() over (partition by name, postal order by lastUpdated) as howRecent
from 
    @dupExample     

/*
    delete duplicates leaving only most recent record based on date updated
    WARNING only one record will be left for each dup even if there are multiple records 
    updated on the same date (see b, d examples)
*/
delete de
from    @dupExample de
    inner join 
    ( select 
        id
        ,row_number() over (partition by name, postal order by lastUpdated desc) as howRecent
        from 
            @dupExample     
    ) der on de.id = der.id
where
    der.howRecent > 1   

/*
    after delete
*/      
select * from @dupExample
```

if you have duplicates with the same dateUpdated you may add some extra criteria to **order by** part to specify which record to delete in such scenario - but hopefully it gives you a good starting point.

Comment: great- thanks, that wasn't quite what i wanted to do- but essentially gave me my solution (see note in my question).